# harddisks change /dev name while running

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, hardware

I know that the assignment of disks to  `/dev`  names can vary at boot, but how the heck can it vary in a session?  I'd swear that happened to me yesterday, `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` changed places, and I think it's happened before tho `/dev/sda` (which is an IDE drive) never gets involved in that.

Comment: Are those internal drives? I could imagine a loose cable in an USB  hub could briefly disconnect all attached drives, and they'd get shuffled when they reappear.

Comment: the names within /dev/ are just names. Distribution avoid using that names (but use UUID for mount)

Comment: All internal.  I almost always refer to partitions by label, still there are those times, like using 'dd' when one uses /dev names, and when they change one can end up doing something catastrophic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming this is Linux, drive letters should only change if the drives disconnect and reconnect. That happens routinely with external USB, but with internal SATA it generally indicates a problem. Common causes include (at least) a loose or defective cable; power supply issues; drive firmware issues; defective and/or dying hard drive; defective SATA controller.

I've see, for example, drives that were on there way out and would sometimes hit some bad sectors, then they'd time out and ignore Linux's SATA resets. So they'd get disconnected. But an hour or two later, they'd finally sort themselves out and re-connect. The solution (of course!) was to replace the failing drives.

Any disconnect/reconnect (or other drive problems) should leave kernel messages; check `dmesg`, `/var/log/kern.log`, or `journalctl -b 0 -k`, etc. for disk messages. Also check drive status with `smartctl`.

Finally, at least on Linux with udev, there are stable names in `/dev`. Look in `/dev/disk/by-id/`. You can use those names with `dd`, etc.

Comment: Excellent. Yeah, I know how to use stable names, still I think you nailed it -- in the log there are errors in red, so, as you say, there was some sort of disconnect, reconnect.  What this means is that any such change in '/dev' name indicates trouble ... and I know I have a failing disk so it all comes together.